# updating resource undefined method `valid?' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, controller

I have some validations for my Lesson model, and I'm able to highlight validation problems on the controller under the create action with the `valid?` method. However, if I try to `valid?` in an analogous manner, I get `undefined method`valid?' for false:FalseClass` How can I go about validating my edit form upon submission, such that it renders the edit form again if the validation doesn't pass?

Lesson model:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :words, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 55 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :subject, presence: true, length: { maximum: 55 }
  validates :difficulty, presence: true, numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 5 }
end
```

Controller:

```
class Teacher::LessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :require_authorized_for_current_lesson, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def show
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @lesson = Lesson.new
  end

  def edit
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @lesson = current_user.lessons.create(lesson_params)
    if @lesson.valid?
      redirect_to teacher_lesson_path(@lesson)
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    @lesson = current_lesson.update_attributes(lesson_params)
    if @lesson.valid?
      redirect_to teacher_lesson_path(current_lesson)
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private
    def require_authorized_for_current_lesson
      if current_lesson.user != current_user
        render text: "Unauthorized", status: :unauthorized
      end
    end

    def current_lesson
      @current_lesson ||= Lesson.find(params[:id])
    end

    def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:title, :description, :subject, :difficulty)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see an error that looks like `undefined method 'valid?' for 'false:FalseClass`

That means that wherever you call the method `:valid?`, the object on which you are calling it is not the object you expect, it is instead just `false`

So you have two instances in your code where you are calling `@lesson.valid?`, which means one or both of the assignments of `@lesson` is sometimes returning false.

In the [docs of create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class), it says: `The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.`

In the [docs of update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes), it says: `If the object is invalid, the saving will fail and false will be returned.`

So it looks like your problem is with `update_attributes`, which apparently just returns `false` if your update was unsuccessful.